# Using path wildcards in git log

Tags: git, wildcard, git-log

I have a file down deep in my git tree:

```
$ git ls-files | grep /Expression.java
sm/src/main/java/cl/utilities/sm/Expression.java
```

I'd like to get a log of its activity without having to type the whole path.  Basically I want this output:

```
$ git log --oneline -2 sm/src/main/java/cl/utilities/sm/Expression.java
2718cdc cleaned up some warnings
f30cf15 Added missing @Overrides
```

... but without having to type `sm/src/main/java/cl/utilities/sm`.  I tried lots of things, but none of them worked:

```
$ git log -- \*/Expression.java
$ git log -- \*Expression.java
$ git log -- \*\*/Expression.java
$ git log -- '*/Expression.java'
$ git log -- '**/Expression.java'
```

Comment: git log -- \*/Expression.java should work, weird

Comment: In my Windows 7 command shell git log "*/Expression.java" works, but single quotes do not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a wildcard, no escapes or quotes required:

```
git log -- */Expression.java
```

Tested on Windows 7 in cmd shell and git bash.

Depending on your shell, you may need quotes -- if single quotes don't work, try double quotes.

Comment: Confirmed that this works for me now.  It looks like I was the victim of a bug present in a few versions of git available around this time.  The fix, as mentioned in http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2012/01/git-1776-1784-and-179-rc2.html, is https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c8eeb8.  It first showed up in 1.7.7.6, released just a couple of months before I asked my question.

Answer (score 3):

use `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'Expression.java' | xargs git log --oneline -2
```

Comment: That assumes the file exists locally. What if you want to log a file that has been deleted?

Answer (score 3):

With git 2.8 (March 2016), wildcards are more firmly supported both as **[pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec)** or **[refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt)**.

See [commit aac4fac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aac4fac1689f7d1414523d2ac96f1c737ee53b71), [commit df714f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df714f81a709dda9552f137ccd2a3510119298ad), [commit 1cc777d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cc777de6f4396f578e0f5e6b1a5ec23b96a52f0) (10 Feb 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e6a6a76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6a6a768ca472afed90adbbd786e5c04fff6be7b), 24 Feb 2016)</sup>

That means that:

- wilcard works with pathspecs:

  ```
    git log -- "*.t"
    # or
    git log    "*.t"
  ```
- wildcard works with refspecs (when searching for a commit message starting with '`b`' for instance):

  ```
    git log "HEAD^{/b.*}" --
    # or
    git log "HEAD^{/b.*}
  ```

Comment: would you mind linking to docs or explaining what exactly the refspecs format does here?

Comment: @Razor Sure thing. I have edited the answer to add the requested link.