# Git checkout using wildcard to a specific revision

Tags: git, wildcard, checkout, revision

I have been seeking it on Google for 2 hours and still can't find the solution.

I want to checkout all files with wildcard to a specific revision. I used following command:

```
git checkout 663090b1c 'src/app/**/*.spec.ts'
```

But it says:

```
error: pathspec 'src/app/**/*.spec.ts' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does commit `663090b1c` contain any files that match the `src/app/app/**/*.spec.ts` pathspec? (Try `git ls-tree -r 663090b1c` and search for files whose name starts with `src/app/app/`, contains any number of directories, and ends with `*.spec.ts`.)

Comment: @torek Sorry, it was  my copy/paste issue. I have updated it.

Comment: Ah, then search the `git ls-tree -r 663090b1c` output for the non-doubled `app/` file names.

Comment: I tried your commands and it showed many changed files with `*.spec.ts`.

Comment: `git ls-tree` doesn't show *changed* files, it just shows *files*. You specified files that are specifically named `src/app/<something>.spec.ts`—just ending in `.spec.ts` is not sufficient; their names must *start* with `src/app/` as well. If such files exist, `git checkout` really should have extracted them. One other important item: are you currently in the *top level* of your work-tree, or a subdirectory?

Comment: Yeah, it showed only files only. For example:

```100644 blob <hidden_hash> src/app/component/<hidden>.component.spec.ts```

And I am at the project root.

Comment: OK, then it seems like that *should* have worked. ... Interesting, I *can* seem to reproduce the problem in a different repository. Not sure yet why (and will be off line for a while and can't look into it further at the moment).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this should work, but clearly it doesn't.  Here's the effect of using the most recent Git (which you can get at https://github.com/git/git) on `Documentation/**/*.txt`.

I built Git, then used the system Git (at 2.21, slightly behind this version which is `2.22.0.545.g9c9b961d7e`) to do this:

```
$ rm Documentation/*/*.txt
$ git status --short | head
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.1.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.2.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.3.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.4.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.5.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.6.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.7.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.1.1.txt
 D Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.1.2.txt
$ git checkout -- 'Documentation/**/*.txt'
$ git status --short | head
$
```

Now, however:

```
$ ./git checkout HEAD -- 'Documentation/**/*.txt'
error: pathspec 'Documentation/**/*.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

It seems that pathspecs work when used with the index, but not when used with a commit hash.

As a workaround—note that this workaround is somewhat defective, though you can patch around it further—you can first read the desired commit into a temporary index, then do the `git checkout` from the temporary index.  The following script is completely untested.

```
#! /bin/sh
# git-co-c-ps: git checkout <commit> <pathspec>
# work around a bug in which combining <commit> and <pathspec> does not work
. git-sh-setup
case $# in
2) ;;
*) die "usage: $0 <commit> <pathspec>";;
esac

hash=$(git rev-parse "$1^{commit}") || exit 1
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit 1
rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE
trap "rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE" 0 1 2 3 15
git read-tree "$hash" || exit 1
git checkout -- "$2"
```

The (untested) idea here is to read the commit specified by "$1" into a temporary index.  (We could relax the `^{commit}` to be just `^{tree}` as any tree-ish should suffice.)  Then, having read that into a temporary index, we use the mode of "git checkout" with a pathspec ($2) that works, using the temporary index.  This writes to the work-tree.

The defect is that the now-updated work-tree files are not also updated in the index.  A real `git checkout` would have copied these same files to the index.  It should be possible to unset `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` and `git add` the added files to the real index.  This is left as an exercise.  Note that it is not as trivial as just `git add -- "$2"` since some work-tree files may be in the work-tree *not* because they were read into the temporary index by the `git read-tree` operation, but rather because they were already in the work-tree.  (Some may be tracked and modified-but-not-yet-staged/added, and others may be untracked.)

Another, perhaps better, workaround is to use `git ls-files` on the temporary index, to find the files of interest.  Use `xargs` or similar to pass these file names to a `git checkout` that is run without the temporary index:

```
files_file=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $files_file" 0 1 2 3 15
(
    export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit 125
    rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE
    trap "rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE" 0 1 2 3 15
    git read-tree $hash
    git ls-files -z -- "$2"
) > $files_file
# if the inner shell exited with an error, exit now
case $? in 125) exit 1;; esac
xargs -0 ...
```

(Filling in the rest of this to make a usable Git shell command is also left as an exercise.)

Comment: Note: I have see wildcard use with pathspec in git log (since Git 2.8): https://stackoverflow.com/a/35622183/6309. But it does not seem to work with git checkout indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to check first a find command:

```
find . src/app/**/*.spec.ts
```

See if the list is correct.
As a workaround, you can then do:

```
find . src/app/**/*.spec.ts | xargs git checkout <sha1> -- 
# or 
find . src/app/**/*.spec.ts -exec git checkout <sha1> -- {} \;
```